# I want to display data in Crystal Report, But I don't understand what is the problem with my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from SIZENN where INVOICENO ='" + textBoxINVOICENO.Text + "', ";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(ds, "SIZENN");

CRYRPTT myReport = new CRYRPTT();
myReport.SetDataSource(ds);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

con.Close();
```

I want to show data in a Crystal Report, but I don't understand what the exact problem is with my code.

Comment: **(1)** ***NEVER EVER*** build your SQL commands like that !! Use **parametrized queries**, always, no exceptions. **(2)** what exactly **is** your problem? Do you get an error - if so - what error? **(3)** why do you first execute the `SELECT` query with `.ExecuteNonQuery()` (that won't do any good, since you can't return any data from that call), and then you execute it **again**, with the `adp.Fill()` command ........

Comment: This is the error I am getting  An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ','.  // Please clarify parametrized queries

Comment: See here: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx . Most likely, if you're using a properly parametrized query, that error will go away automagically ...